# Ajax File Upload Progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm using the following code to upload file to server,

```
    function FileUpload(SomestringParameter) {
var files = $("#file1").get(0).files;
if (files.length > 0) {
    if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
        var data = new FormData();
        for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
            data.append("file" + i, files[i]);
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:50443/UploadFile/" + SomestringParameter,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: data,
        success: function (results) {
            alert(results);
            for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                alert(results[i]);
            }
        }
    });

} 
else {
    alert("This browser doesn't support HTML5 multiple file uploads!");
}
}
}
```

I like to use this plugin, jquery mobile progress bar, https://github.com/tolis-e/jQuery-Mobile-Progress-Bar-with-Percentage

**How can I show that progress bar based on percent of file uploaded on to the server?.**

I'm using web api on the server side to deal with the file uploaded.

Comment: _“I'm using web api on the server side to deal with the file uploaded.”_ – what is “web api”?

Comment: Asp.net web api service..

Comment: Well then you’ll have to figure out in what way that is able to report progress back to the client while the upload is in progress.